# Extracting a player name starting at the start of string up to the first occurrence of a certain word

Tags: r, regex

This should be a layup. Obviously I'm still shaky with regex but I'm trying to do a simple call that pulls a name out of a string. Here are a couple simple examples but I suspect there will bases with non-alpha characters in the last name somewhere down the line.

I'm trying to find the name of the player who shoots the ball. Either they "makes" or "misses" right after their name:

```
D. Rodman makes 2-pt layup  (assist by L. Longley)
M. Jordan misses 2-pt jump shot from 15 ft
```

I used a regex generator and got most of it but for some reason the capture group included all the way up to including the `m` in either `makes` or `misses`. Anyway, would love to know how to do this using a lookaround function so I get more exp with how they behave.

Here is what I tried:

```
(?<=[ makes| misses])[A-Z]\. [A-Z][a-z]+
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the capture group included all the way up to including the m in either makes or misses"? Please add the expression and code to the question. Why do you need a lookbehind? I doubt you need it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I lost the code but I got it to return "D. Rodman m" and "M. Jordan m" for example

Comment: Try `sub("^(.*?)\\s+(?:misses|makes)\\b.*$", "\\1", x)`

Comment: Try `.+?(?=\s*(?:misses|makes))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works but it doesn't leave cases in which makes or misses isnt in the string. sorry I should have clarified that. some strings isn't a shot and therefore doesn't contain misses or makes and I need those to stay blank

Comment: Ok, but I can only answer a question as it is written, I can't read your mind. See two solutions in my answer. I can add a third if you say those are not working in the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew truer words never spoken. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- c("D. Rodman makes 2-pt layup  (assist by L. Longley)",
"M. Jordan misses 2-pt jump shot from 15 ft")
sub("^(.*?)\\s+(?:misses|makes)\\b.*", "\\1", x)
# => [1] "D. Rodman" "M. Jordan"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0gVged/1)  and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/XoZ1Sl).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:misses|makes)` - `misses` or `makes` substring
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible.

*stringr* solution based on the regex above:

```
library(stringr)
stringr::str_extract(x, "^.*?(?=\\s+(?:misses|makes)\\b)")
```

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/OVMVT83476). Details:

- `^.*?` - start of string and then 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s+(?:misses|makes)\b)` - up to the leftmost occurrence of 1+ whitespaces and then `misses` or `makes` words.

Comment: Amazing. It pulls all the random guys with two last names and hyphens etc. I really thank you for the explanation so I can better understand this!